# Giving floating point values to the css "left" of an html tag Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

if I do `$("#myid").css("left",15.67);` on Chrome or Firefox, the resultant left value become 15.67px but for IE 8 it only remains 15px.

Any fix for this?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units: _“In cases where the used length cannot be supported, user agents must approximate it in the actual value.”_

Comment: You mean that i would have to work with integral values only? Also whats strange is that if I edit the value of left in the developer tools panel, IE8 accepts the value and does not round it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `em` instead of `px` for IE. So `15.67px` would be around `1.2em`

```
$("#myid").css("left","1.2em");
```

***Update***

Actually it seems that the problem may be subpixel rendering. IE 9 or below does not support it and you con't use half a pixel (pixel being the smallest thing).

IE 10, Chrome and Firefox on the other hand do support it.

Comment: 1.2 em = 20px. So i tried for 1.285px(20.56px) [$("#myid").css("left","1.285em");] but this resulted in 21px

Comment: Ah right, 1em should be equal to the font-size so it's different depending on it

Comment: I meant that if you set font-size:15px; that results in 1em = 15px;